# How to implement disappearing animations in VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to test effect animations on shapes in a VBA procedure.

I've already achieved one which is adding some new animations in the *MainSequence*, defining in which position in the *Timeline*... but I am not able to create disapearing animations.

I checked in the beginning of the code some already there...and the EffectType seems to return the same value as related appearing animation, so that I sadly believe there's no way of creating disapearing animations in VBA.

Please tell me I am wrong, I have to do the same creations on over 300 slides...

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and doing this manually, to see which properties the macro impacts?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I didn't know that there is a macro recorder for PowerPoint too. I thought only Excel has this great option. Could you please help me find it in PowerPoint too?

Comment: Assuming you have office 2007 or later, it's in the same place for PowerPoint as it is for Excel - View Ribbon > Macros.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-happened-to-the-macro-recorder-cad40737-3c4d-4640-8263-6f6999b3b31b http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-powerpoint/does-powerpoint-2010-include-record-macro/18268723-ede5-47e4-b776-0c714681d580?auth=1 It seems there **was** a macro recorder (but no more) in PowerPoint before 2007. All I can say for sure is that in my Office 2016 version there is no such button.

Comment: @Ralph Ah, my apologies - I use Office 2007 at work so wasn't aware that this had changed. It's a shame that they would remove it; not sure why they would. This link may have some info to help you with your question: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-customize/vba-add-an-animation-and-then-delete-the-shapes/e546fd64-fc01-4ce1-b356-0af1a167145e?auth=1

Comment: The link only talk about "positive" EffectId which means appearing animations. They used the Visible field to make shapes disapear...When I want to add a disapearing effect (fade for exemple)...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are wrong, however documentation to that is... well, I guess you know that already.

Here's the trick. To add a disappearing animation you have to add appearing animation but set it's 'Exit' property to 'msoTrue'

Take a look at this code example:

```
Private Sub SetAnimation()
    Dim effNewEffect As Effect

    With ActiveWindow.View.Slide
        Set effNewEffect = .TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(.Shapes(.Shapes.Count), msoAnimEffectAppear, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious, Index:=-1)
    End With
    effNewEffect.Timing.TriggerDelayTime = 1.0
    effNewEffect.Exit = msoTrue
End Sub
```

It will add a Disappear animation to the last Shape in a current slide as the last in the MainSequence with delay 1.0 s to the previous animation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use an "Exit" property on the "Effect" object.

The "Exit" property is msoFalse by default.

Answer (score -1):

Can't believe I have the answer to anything but here goes.

1. Select object to disappear
2. Go to animations an select fade out (red one)
3. Open animation pane
4. go to the click down menu for the object
5. Select Effect options
6. Go to timing menu
7. Click triggers
8. Click "start effect on click of" and find the object number that matches the one on the animation panel for it.
9. Job done.

Comment: Did you notice it's about VBA solution?