# How to make an object dissappear in PPT using VBA?

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

I am trying to make an object disappear in PPT using VBA. I can make the object appear in many ways but I don't know how to make it disappear.

I wrote the code below but it does not work. It looks like "msoAnimEffectDisappear" does not exist.

```
Set Benny = ActiveWindow.View.Slide

 ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("textbox 114").Select

y = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Name

Set Sh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(y)

Benny.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect Sh, msoAnimEffectDisappear, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement disappearing animations in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946102/how-to-implement-disappearing-animations-in-vba)

Comment: Quick answer: assign the return value of `AddEffect` to `effect`, then set `effect.Exit = True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("textbox 114").Visible = False
```

Comment: Thank you very much  for the answer. It works  by itself,  but it is not integrate it in the animation pan.

Comment: I didn't understand that you needed it to be part of the animation sequence.  You might try applying an exit animation manually then examining its properties in VBA to see how it's done.

Comment: Stave thanks for your suggestion. I already tried that and it does not help at all.